# How to convert from 2-2-21 08:15 AM to yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM in Google Sheets?

Tags: date, google-sheets, datetime-format

I have a lot of weirdly formatted dates. For example:

```
2-2-21 08:15 AM
1-29-21 8:01 AM
1-26-21 3:00 PM
1-26-21 8:00 AM
12-26-20 3:10 AM
12-15-20 8:00 AM
```

Can I convert them to yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM in Google Sheets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A1:A="",,TEXT(DATE(
 IFERROR(20&REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A, "-(\d+) "), YEAR(A1:A))*1, 
 IFERROR(   REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A, "\d+"),    MONTH(A1:A))*1,
 IFERROR(   REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A, "-(\d+)"),   DAY(A1:A))*1)+
 IFERROR(TIMEVALUE(A1:A), REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A, "\d+:\d+")+
 IF(REGEXMATCH(A1:A, "PM"), 0.5, 0)), "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm")))
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, all in one cell! Thanks! But the 3:00 PM should be 15:00. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Thank you so much! I have also improved this to convert to Unix Timestamp, since I needed it.
This is for unix timestamp
=DATEVALUE(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(K135="",,DATE(
 IFERROR(20&REGEXEXTRACT(K135, "-(\d+) "), YEAR(K135))*1, 
 IFERROR(   REGEXEXTRACT(K135, "\d+"),    MONTH(K135))*1,
 IFERROR(   REGEXEXTRACT(K135, "-(\d+)"),   DAY(K135))*1))))
+IFERROR(TIMEVALUE(K135), REGEXEXTRACT(K135, "\d+:\d+")+
 IF(REGEXMATCH(K135, "PM"), 0.5, 0))